# Using a Barcode Scanner on an Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, emulation, barcode-scanner

Right now I'm trying to write an app that uses the barcode scanner. It works fine when I test it out on my tablet, prompting users to download the app if they don't have it, however the issue that I run into is that I currently don't have access to my tablet or other hardware to test it out. I am currently using an emulator that doesn't have a barcode scanner installed on it.

Is there a way for me to download and install the barcode scanner on the emulator, or otherwise include something that will allow me to run the scanner from the emulator?

Comment: we are not getting virtual camera in emulator.when runnning scanner app we must have camera in our device.

Comment: Yes I have a camera set up to work through my computer webcam

Comment: in your emualator,camera is open or not?

Comment: no. but my code passes the proper intents to zxing so that it can call something that qualifies as a barcode scanner app

Comment: might it be as simple as an import? or might it be that I just don't actually have a working camera?

Comment: I don't know how to ask you directly Sean O'Toole, but why was it recommended that I take out the formatting and the answer. I was recommended to add the bold and italics for clarity.

Comment: Hi Michael, we don't generally put answers in the questions themselves as that kinda breaks the flow of a Q&A site. As I was removing the answer I also chose to remove the formatting that I felt to be more noise than anything else, a 'BUT' in bold, capital letters draws the eyes away from the question itself. Stack Overflow is community driven though so by all means, if you feel that the question would be clearer with some choice formatting then feel free to add it back in. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking how you install the Barcode Scanner application without Google Play on the virtual device?

Download the `.apk` file for the latest Barcode Scanner ([v4.5.1](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=BarcodeScanner-4.5.1.apk) right now) from the [project site](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list).

Then you should be able to run `adb install BarcodeScanner-4.5.1apk` wherever you downloaded it, while the emulator is

Comment: Thank you for your response and your edit! They were very helpful!